# Preventing Meteor from removing MiniMongo data already sent to client when publish changes

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactive-programming, meteor-publications

I have noticed that when I change the published cursor - NOT the data the cursor points to, but the whole cursor - Meteor will send a `removed` message to the client for all documents that do not appear in the new cursor.
What I mean in more technical terms:

```
// client side
Tracker.autorun(function() {
    var someReactiveVar = someReactiveVar.get(); 
    Meteor.subscribe('myPublication', someReactiveVar);
}
...
// server side
Meteor.publish('myPublication', function() {
    var someParameter = arguments[0];
    return myCollection.find({ someAttribute: someParameter });
});
```

Now when `someReactiveVar` changes, all documents that had been sent to the client side MiniMongo `myCollection` will be removed (if they are not part of the new cursor). In certain cases this is what you will want, but my question simply is: can I prevent this? How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's some magic happening here, when you perform `Meteor.subscribe` inside a `Tracker.autorun`. Basically, it will `.stop()` the old subscription after each run.

You have two options,

1- Keep multiple subscriptions alive, by using a `nonreactive` block.

Note: You'll have to write some code to clean-up `subHandles`.

```
var subHandles = [];
Tracker.autorun(function(){
  var someReactiveVal = someReactiveVar.get();
  Tracker.nonreactive(function(){
    var subHandle = Meteor.subscribe('myPublication', someReactiveVal);
    subHandles.push(subHandle);
  });
});
```

2- Make your subscription take multiple values, eg

Note: This will make both sets of data available on the client, but may not stop it being re-transmitted.

```
Template.myTemplate.events({
   'click mybutton': function(){
      var newVal = getNewVal();
      var arrayOfValues = someReactiveVar.get();
      arrayOfValues.push(newVal);
      someReactiveVar.set(arrayOfValues);
   }
})

// client side
Tracker.autorun(function() {
    var arrayOfValues = someReactiveVar.get(); 
    Meteor.subscribe('myPublication', arrayOfValues);
}
...
// server side
Meteor.publish('myPublication', function(arrayOfValues) {
    return myCollection.find({ 
      someAttribute: {$in: arrayOfValues} 
    });
});
```

Comment: Interesting! I like both solutions, though I am not totally sure if the 2nd would work: will Meteor not first remove stuff from the old subscription/publication and the re-transfer it? That is just what I want to avoid!

Comment: Depends on your definition of work ;-). Yes it probably would send all the data down the wire again. That may be preferable to managing `subHandles` for some use-cases.

Comment: Well it (the 2nd solution) kind of does not fulfill what I was looking for - since strictly speaking it does not prevent Meteor from removing already sent documents. It just re-sends them. You could point this out in your answer. But nice explanation, thanks!